# Python: How to resample incoming stream of data on a rolling basis

Tags: python, database, bigdata, resampling

We're creating an application that reads timeseries data (e.g. vehicle speed) line-by-line from a large database with millions of lines. The data might look like below:

```
54.2
55.3
55.4
...
77.2
77.1
77.5
```

The stream would start by reading `54.2`, then `55.3`, etc. The reader should initially take the 1st 200 samples as equal to the raw data 1:1. When more samples are added, the reader should start re-sampling the data to create a downsampled version of the raw data to ensure we stay with only 200 re-sampled observations

The purpose is to plot the data in Dash by Plot.ly - using only the relevant amount of data to create the plot. The need for re-sampling is to avoid RAM issues, as well as to ensure that we do not transfer unnecessary amounts from the backend to the client's frontend interface.

We'd appreciate any suggestions for Python libraries that can help with this type of re-sampling.

Comment: Plaese formulate more clear your requirement. Do you want to *sample a stream*?

Comment: I've tried clarifying the question